# (Java) How do I play sound file while connecting to phone by 56k modem?

Tags: java, audio, playback, modem

Now I have a modem Hayes V92 56k. I used JSSC lib for control this modem via serial port. I have a audio file. Now I want use modem to dial to another phone and I want to play that audio file while modem and phone are connected.
How do I do that with Java + JSSC lib??? @@
Thank for your answers!!!
P/S:
I connected to other phone successfully. But I dont know to play that sound and send to phone @@

Comment: What did you try? Where's your code?

Comment: Would this happen to be a cold-calling bot you're writing?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: as @C-Otto said, include your code. When you play the audio file, it will probably play faster than you recieve it. I suggest reading the entire file, then play it. We can't suggest anything because you haven't included code.